# Make file possible accidental order-only dependency?

Tags: makefile

I am pulling out my hair trying to debug an issue with make.  It seems like make is randomly treating certain prerequisites as order-only prerequisites, resulting in them being left out of the static library target that depends on them. Most of the time the build works find but occasionaly some .cpp files are built but not included in the .a.  When i run Make with --debug I see the following output for the suspect prerequisites.

```
Prerequisite `blah.o' is newer than target `/path/to/foo.a`
Prerequisite `blah1.o' is newer than target `/path/to/foo.a`
Prerequisite `blah2.o' is newer than target `/path/to/foo.a`
No need to remake target `/path/to/foo.a'
```

For all of the prereqs that do make it into the .a the last line is "Must remate target /path/to/foo.a" as I would expect.

Because make is invoked in several subdirectories, target /path/to/foo.a is updated several times.  We are not running make in parallel so I don't think updates to the file are stomping each other.  It seems that make is deliberately not updating the .a file despite the fact that the .o's are newer. The recipe to make foo.a is as follows:

```
$(OBJLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR)     $(ARFLAGS) $(OBJLIB) $?
```

Where ARFLAGS=rv and OBJLIB would be /path/to/foo.a.

Am i right in thinking that the .o files are being treated as order-only dependencies? Is there something else I'm missing here? I am using $(info) to output the contents of OBJLIB and OBJS and there are no errant pipe ('|') characters making their way into the variable contents that would induce order-only dependencies.

Comment: I seriously doubt that it's a spurious setting of objects to order-only.  Something else is going on.  What version of make are you using?  What platform are you building on?  Assuming there's not something else going on that's not suggested above, it seems like a bug: saying that a prerequisite is newer than the target, then not building the target, looks wrong.  You can try the prerelease of the next version to see if that helps: ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.99.90.tar.bz2

Comment: Building on fedora 15 x86_64, make 3.82.  I'll try a new version of make and see if there is a different result.

Comment: It would help if you gave us a minimal complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer had nothing to do with make.  As far as I can tell the filesystem is the real culprit.  Several people were experiencing success with the build but I was not.  The difference between our systems which were using a common build environment was that I was building on an ext3 filesystem while they were using an ext4 filesystem.

Since ext3 does not support sub-1s timestamps (ext4 does) in some cases when the rule was invoked with only a few CPP files they were being compiled in the same second that the archive was updated by a previous invocation and everything was ending up with the same timestamps.  Copying the directory over to an ext4 filesystem fixed the issue.

The real fix is to write a proper set of make rules but at least we have an answer as to why it was working for everyone but me.

Comment: But there is a make related problem as well. See my answer above. You folks are using the $? variable (incorrectly). Should be using $^. Using $? causes only *changed* dependencies to end up in the archive. What you want it for *all* the dependencies to end up in the archive. For that you need to use $^.

Comment: @Ziffusion: that's not true.  The archiver has the nice feature that it can incrementally add or remove objects from an archive.  There's no need to completely delete and recreate an archive from scratch, just because a few objects have changed.  You can just replace the changed objects.

Comment: Oh recursive make, how I do loathe thee... This is exactly the kind of situation described in [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). I recognize that a non-recursive setup is difficult to implement--especially for a large, existing codebase--but it avoids the problem of things getting run in the wrong order.

Comment: I spent the 2 days since asking this question rewriting the build system to use non recursive make.  @Ziffusion - I Tried your suggestion, it still does not correct the issue. Make doesn't even bother updating the library because the timestamp resolution is too low.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned several updates to the .a file because make is invoked in different subdirectories. Probably the message

```
No need to remake target `/path/to/foo.a'
```

comes from one subdirectory, and `is newer`- from another. Consider building the lib out of all objects in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$(OBJLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR)     $(ARFLAGS) $(OBJLIB) $^
```

Your problem is that the variable $? is a list of dependencies that are *newer* than the target, while $^ is a list of *all* dependencies.

Also, you can use $@ for to be more idiomatic.

```
$(OBJLIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR)     $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
```